# Can we use the Artifactory plugin to copy artifacts between different paths within the same repository?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

The Background: The downstream pipelines do the builds and archive the artifacts to path-1 in Artifactory. The upstream pipeline (caller) needs to copy some artifacts of the downstream to a separate path for delivery with the upstream pipeline build num. The current practice is downloading the artifacts and uploading them but I wonder if I could remotely copy/move them in Artifactory to avoid web traffic.

My question: Is it possible to use the Artifactory plugin to copy artifacts between different paths within the same Artifactory repository? This a reminder that both the source and target paths are within the same Artifactory instance.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Copy Artifacts') {
      steps {
        script {
          // Set the source and target paths within the Artifactory repository
          def sourceRepo = 'libs-release-local'
          def sourcePath = 'path/to/source'
          def targetRepo = 'libs-release-local'
          def targetPath = 'path/to/target'

          // Copy the artifacts using the Artifactory plugin and capture build information
          def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory-server-id')
          def rtBuildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
          server.copy {
            spec {
              fromRepo(sourceRepo)
              includePatterns(sourcePath + '/*')
              intoRepo(targetRepo)
              intoFolder(targetPath)
            }
            buildInfo rtBuildInfo
          }

          // Publish the captured build information to Artifactory
          server.publishBuildInfo(rtBuildInfo)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I was trying to use `Artifactory.server.copy`, I got below error. Looks like this API doesn't exist at all.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.ArtifactoryServer.copy() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1712040b]
Possible solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), notify(), wait(), every(), grep()
```

If is it impossible, do you have any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifactory) does not support this capability, however the new [Jenkins JFrog plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jfrog) does. The new plugin makes it simple to install and perform JFrog CLI commands.

In the new plugin you could do the following:

```java
tools {
    jfrog 'jfrog-cli'
}

jf 'rt cp libs-release-local/path/to/source libs-release-local/path/to/target'
```

Read more about it here:

- [Jenkins JFrog Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jfrog/#plugin-content-overview)
- [How to Use the JFrog Plugin in Jenkins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm2i2Zl-m9E)